# How to force a page to a A4 using pdfkit (python)

Tags: python, html, pdf, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I have a html page that i would to convert to pdf. My problem is that it don't fit on a A4, and I obtain 2 pages instead of 1. When I use `'page-size': 'a3'` it fit perfectly, but I want a A4 pdf. Changing DPI or disabling smart shrinking does not change anything.

How can i make it a A4, or at least, convert my A3 to a A4 ?

Comment: you have tried `options={'page-size':'A4', 'dpi':400}`?

Comment: Yes, and as i said, i obtain 2 pages. I tried changing dpi from 150 to 600 but it does not change anything.

Comment: Are you able to share the webpage for us to experiment with?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Comment: 0

Refer a below URL:

https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/

Hope,it's useful.

Thanks..Happy coding..!